# Building an LSTM net with an embedding layer in Keras

Tags: neural-network, keras, lstm

I want to create a Keras model consisting of an embedding layer, followed by two LSTMs with dropout 0.5, and lastly a dense layer with a softmax activation.

The first LSTM should propagate the sequential output to the second layer, while in the second I am only interested in getting the hidden state of the LSTM after processing the whole sequence.

I tried the following:

```
sentence_indices = Input(input_shape, dtype = 'int32')

embedding_layer = pretrained_embedding_layer(word_to_vec_map, word_to_index)

embeddings = embedding_layer(sentence_indices)
# Propagate the embeddings through an LSTM layer with 128-dimensional hidden state
X = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, dropout = 0.5)(embeddings)

# Propagate X trough another LSTM layer with 128-dimensional hidden state
X = LSTM(128, return_sequences=False, return_state=True, dropout = 0.5)(X)

# Propagate X through a Dense layer with softmax activation to get back a batch of 5-dimensional vectors.
X = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(X)

# Create Model instance which converts sentence_indices into X.
model = Model(inputs=[sentence_indices], outputs=[X])
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Layer dense_5 expects 1 inputs, but it received 3 input tensors. Input received: [<tf.Tensor 'lstm_10/TensorArrayReadV3:0' shape=(?, 128) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'lstm_10/while/Exit_2:0' shape=(?, 128) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'lstm_10/while/Exit_3:0' shape=(?, 128) dtype=float32>]
```

Clearly LSTM is not returning an output of the shape I expect. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `return_state=True`, then `LSTM(...)(X)` returns three things: the outputs, the last hidden state and the last cell state.

So instead of `X = LSTM(128, return_sequences=False, return_state=True, dropout = 0.5)(X)`, do `X, h, c = LSTM(128, return_sequences=False, return_state=True, dropout = 0.5)(X)`

See [here](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the help