# Adding a Pre-Trained Word Embedding into an Encoder Decoder

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, word-embedding, encoder-decoder

I would like to add a Pretrained Word Embedding to my Encoder-Decoder.  Below is my code:

```
# Define an Encoder
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, nEncoderToken))
encoder = LSTM(embedding_dim, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Define a Decoder
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, nDecoderToken))
decoder_lstm = LSTM(embedding_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = Dense(nDecoderToken, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
```

I tried many ways but I just couldn't get it.

Comment: It looks like keras to me. I suppose, you could simply pass the loaded embeddings matrix to the `embeddings_initializer` or `weights` parameter in the Embeddings layer placed just before LSTM layer, instead of Input layer?

Comment: When I try doing that, I get dimension issues.

Either, `Error when checking input: expected input_0 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 50, 780)`
Or, `Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_0: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4`

Comment: If I remove the Input layer, then I get the Error,
`Layer lstm_0 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor.`
So I am a little stumped ~

Comment: Simplest solution, I think, would be to use the the sequential model (in general), but if you'd like to stick to this format, take a look at the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48850424/building-an-lstm-net-with-an-embedding-layer-in-keras and specifically example linked there https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?